# Shared Element Transition with Material Motion?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-transitions

I'm trying to transition from a view in a recycler view to a view in a different activity, but instead of smoothly transitioning, it flicks to the new content immediately and then moves to the new position.
I tried solving this issue with "Material Motion" but there's nearly no info about it on the java side.